# Reload my site when the window/browser gets resized (doesn't work in internet explorer)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, resize, reload

I used this code in my < head >:

```
<script>$(window).on('resize',function(){location.reload();});</script>
```

How can I get this to work in internet Explorer?

Comment: Ugh, why would you do this?

Comment: Make sure that's a feature that your users want.  Personally, I think that would make an unpleasant experience.  Why do you want to reload the page if the browser is resized?

Comment: www.ivoklerk.com/ilto is where i use it. I use this because when you tilt your ipad from landscape to portrait it doesn't go wrong

Comment: Maybe you can find the `document.body.width` and see if it changes in a `setInterval()`?

Comment: So it's also good if I can find a way that the javascript is disabled in IE

Comment: IE is terrible.  Also, there is something called a `<noscript>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(window).bind('resize',function(){
         window.location.href = window.location.href;
      });
   </script>
 </head>
```

you can use "on" too.

caveat: I agree with the previous comments made by others. This might be a bad user experience.

Comment: I understand, it's a temporary solution. But your code doesn't work on chrome, i'm testing it now..

Comment: I just have to place this between <script> and </script> in the <head> right?

Comment: @user3124133 Yes, and ensure you have included jQuery.

Comment: @user3124133  do you have jQuery library loaded into your page?

Comment: Yes i have jQuery loaded

Answer (score 0):

I would use either CSS media queries or percent values for widths and margins.  Reloading the page is generally a bad idea.  The media queries and percent values will update themselves automatically when the browser is resized.

[Media Query starting point](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Percentage values are simple: `width: 100%`.  Just play around with it.

Comment: I know but i Really don't know how to do this.. www.ivoklerk.com/ilto. You can see that if you load the site in a small windows size and than make it bigger it gets messed up

Comment: @user3124133 No time to start like the present.  You really should learn how to use these.  They are the future of web design.  I added examples and links to get you started.

Comment: yeah i know, but i use a javascript that gives a div a height automatically on load. It's a singlepage website with full screen div's that you can scroll thru

Comment: @user3124133 Then just reassign that height and width on resize.  That is still much better than reloading the whole page.

Comment: Yeah but i don't understand javascript, so that's a mission impossible for me

Comment: @user3124133 Then maybe you should take some time and learn it.  Using prefabricated prices won't get you there.